# Assigning multiple colors of yarn to a crochet project using sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a project for my wife's custom crochet business to develop a data base for her.  Most of her crochet projects use multiple colors of yarn.  I have tried just restricting each project to 6 colors but want to use an undefined number of colors instead.  Can this be done in SQL Server and, if so, what is the best way to do it?  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for consulting work. You might post what objects you have created, tag the Q with design, adding a version wouldn't hurt either. How are you restricting colors? How do you plan to handle multi-colored yarn as there are different types, do you have a list of IDs, what about a lookup table or dim structure, for these 'colors' of yarn.

Comment: How are you representing "color" now, and why would that lead to a limit? A table can have an unlimited number of rows. A column can have any value. Unless you've made the poor decision to represent each color as its own column somehow, you should not be limited. And if you have made that decision, look at normalization.

Comment: Sure this is possible with sql server or any other DBMS. You do this with normalized data structures. Unfortunately this question is entirely too broad.

Comment: I currently have a Yarn table that includes the yarn weight, color and amount on hand.  Right now, I have 6 fields: Yarn1, Yarn2, Yarn3, Yarn4, Yarn5 and Yarn6 in the table for each different type of project that she offers.  I am sure that there is an easier way to do this but I am not sure how.